# Command, alt, control, tab keys in iOS 8 Custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, custom-keyboard

I know that since iOS 7 it is possible to capture keyboard shortcuts in apps using the UIKeyCommand class.

Is it possible to implement the command, alt, control, tab keys in a custom keyboard to fire some keyboard shortcuts like copy, paste or some custom shortcuts defined within each app?

Maybe there is a way to simulate the input from the external keyboard forcing something with UIKeyCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Custom keyboards (that is, onscreen keyboards from the iOS 8 keyboard extension API) insert *text*, they don't send key events. And inserting text is all they can do — the API for custom keyboards is very narrowly defined... presumably for privacy/security reasons.

I know I wouldn't want a keyboard extension randomly performing UI actions in other apps without my involvement. But Apple might think differently if you can provide a good use case in a [feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com)...