# Non-Alphanumeric Key Presses with Custom Keyboard Extension? (Xamarin iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I've created a custom keyboard extension for iOS in Xamarin. I need to pass in modifier key presses like PageUp, Home, Insert, Escape, etc.

Why you might ask? My company has small display register with a 17-key keypad for bio-diesel blending. It's running Linux under the covers and we can VNC into it. We have hundreds of these registers in the field and want a solution that's backwards compatible. The problem is that a lot of the navigation requires modifier keys. This makes navigating with a traditional soft keyboard more trouble than it's worth. So, rather then reinvent the wheel by writing a parallel UI or a custom VNC app, I'm giving a custom keyboard extension a try.

I have an Android version of the keyboard extension working fine. Android allows me to pass in explicit KeyCodes. There are KeyCodes for all the keys on a full keyboard. However, iOS uses basic sting insertion under the covers; and there are no string representations for modifier keys.

Here's my working keypad. (I'll pretty it up later.):

[image]
.

My ViewController is inheriting from UIInputViewController. Here's a snippet of my code behind:

```
  public override void ViewDidLoad()
  {
   base.ViewDidLoad();

   UpButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   LeftButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   RightButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   DownButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   PrintButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   ModeButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   MenuButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   PresetButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   StartButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
   StopButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;

   NextKeyboardButton.AddTarget(this, new Selector("advanceToNextInputMode"), UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
  }

  private void Button_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if (sender == UpButton)
    TextDocumentProxy.InsertText("8");
   else if (sender == LeftButton)
    TextDocumentProxy.InsertText("4");
   else if (sender == RightButton)
    TextDocumentProxy.InsertText("6");
   else if (sender == DownButton)
    TextDocumentProxy.InsertText("2");
   else if (sender == PrintButton)
   {
    // Key.PageUp
   }
   else if (sender == ModeButton)
   {
    // Key.PageDown
   }
   else if (sender == MenuButton)
   {
    // Key.Home
   }
   else if (sender == PresetButton)
   {
    // Key.Insert
   }
   else if (sender == StartButton)
   {
    // Key.Enter
   }
   else if (sender == StopButton)
   {
    // Key.Escape
   }
  }
```

Is there another way to interact with the target of the keyboard other than TextDocumentProxy.InsertText()? If not an explicit KeyCode, how about Unicode?

Thanks all!

Comment: Hi , do you refer to [NextPrevious
Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) this to custom keyboard in IOS.

Comment: I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634523/command-alt-control-tab-keys-in-ios-8-custom-keyboard If this is true then what I'm trying to do may not be possible.

Comment: Sorry for not too much understanding this "iOS uses basic sting insertion under the covers; and there are no string representations for modifier eys.", do you mean wanting to get [keyCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1591574-date?language=objc) from ios ,and by this to invoke special methods .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, your link goes to a NSDate data type page. At any rate, yes. I want to send an explicit keystroke; not a string. In my example code, 'TextDocumentProxy.InsertText("8")' sends an "8" string. I want to explicitly send a number pad 8 keystroke instead. Something like, 'Foo.DoFoo(FooKey.Num8)'.I need to send keys like PageUp, PageDown, Insert, Escape, Home, etc. Keys you find on a normal full keyboard.

Comment: Got it , if have workaround will share here.